# Enable Alt+Ctrl+t to open a terminal in LXDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

How can I enable shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal on Debian in LXDE? I found that this is possible to define in rc.xml file. In LXDE webpage I found message:

```
How do I define LXDE settings system wide?

To define settings for all users you have to edit /usr/share/lxde/openbox/rc.xml that will be copied to user directory ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml on session login.
```

I found two rc.xml files on my PC :

```
root@debianmini:/# find -name rc.xml
./etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml
./etc/xdg/openbox/LXDE/rc.xml
```

And there is no `openbox` directory in `/usr/share/lxde/`

I have edited both of these files with value:

```
<keyboard>
  <chainQuitKey>C-g</chainQuitKey>

   <keybind key="C-A-t">
    <action name="Execute"><command>xterm</command></action>
  </keybind>
....
</keyboard>
```

But this doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you restart openbox after editing?

Comment: yes, I have restarted

Comment: It might make sense to ask such specialized questions in project's maillist/irc.

Comment: Do you have some config-file in home directory with same keybind? Check by `grep 'C-A-T\b' -r ~/\.[^.]* --include="*.xml"`

Comment: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration says that there can also be a user specific file in `~/.config/openbox/`. But the `/etc/` located files should be enough. Have you tried to set something else on some of this files?

Comment: If you edit the lxde-pi-rc.xml configuration file in the .config/openbox directory it will work.